# Split form field value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a script that takes data from one field and populates a second field with part of it. So far it works great :-)

However, now I'd like to just move a part of the value from one field.

**For example**, if a user enters `Helena Bonham-Carter` it would populate the `last_name` field with `Bonham-Carter` and leave the `full_name` value as `Helena Bonham-Carter`.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/ygvtb7yn/

**HTML:**

```
<p><input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Full Name"/></p>
<p><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"></p>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#full_name').keyup(function(){
   $('#last_name').val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: How would you know that it is that last name of type value?what if Joan Marie Bonham-Carter?

Comment: That's a very good point - I'm basically going to treat *anything* after the first space as a last name (even though it could be a middle name, I agree).

Comment: in that case use `$('#last_name').val($(this).val().split(" ")[1]);` but if the input is `Joan Marie Bonham-Carter` last name will `Marie Bonham-Carter`

Comment: @guradio You should make that an answer. The only downside e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/t3by7a09/ is that if you have more than one surname, it doesn't add to last_name field :(

Comment: yes just like if name is `Joan Marie Bonham-Carter`

Comment: IMHO, you should simply provide the different boxes and let the user fill them in as needed. Having worked extensively with programing related to the airline industry (where we work with a lot of names), I can tell you that it is very difficult to foresee all the different ways they are combined

Comment: You can make things much easier if you change the event listener from `keyup` to `change` **Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ygvtb7yn/3/ This will remove the last name from the input. This will work with names such as `Joan Marie Bonham-Carter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript `split()`:

```
$('#full_name').keyup(function(){
   $('#last_name').val(this.value.split(' ')[1]);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygvtb7yn/1/)

--

**Edit:** if it's possible to have more than one space in the name, use the following code:

```
$('#full_name').keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.indexOf(' ') > 0)
        $('#last_name').val(this.value.substr(this.value.indexOf(' ') + 1));
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygvtb7yn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('#last_name').val($(this).val().split(" ")[1]);`

But this doesn't guarantee a correct last name for instances that the first name of the person has two words or when the person enters a middle name.

What this does is basically get the second part of what user inputs. After the space

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me what happens https://jsfiddle.net/t3by7a09/ when you enter the name `Joan Marie Bonham-Carter`?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to tell the user to enter name like first (space) last or what ever in the middle.

```
 $('#last_name').val($(this).val().split(" ")[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand u correctly this may solve your issue

This will solve if no last Name first name is populated to last name
and if Last Name then populates only last name

```js
$('#full_name').keyup(function() {
  var splitedName =$(this).val().split(" ");
  if (splitedName.length > 1)
    $('#last_name').val($(this).val().replace(splitedName[0],""));
  else
    $('#last_name').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Full Name" />
</p>

<p>
  <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
</p>
```

Comment: What about `James Allen Smith`?

Comment: @Delighted Allen Smith will be populated

Comment: Exactly, even though Allen would actually be the middle name or part of the first name.....just saying. It's not really the answer that's bad but the use case itself. There is no good method to do what the OP wants, not really.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want only last name ,

this code below take care of this in case there is middle name also

```
 $('#full_name').keyup(function(){
    full_name  = (this.value).split(" ");
    if(full_name.length>1)
   $('#last_name').val(full_name[full_name.length-1]);
});
```

/if condition checks if full name doesn't have space then it is only first name.

```
full_name[full_name.length-1]
```

to get last name in case there are many middle names

Comment: What about `James Van Der Beek`?

Comment: then last name is  "Beek" , according to name convention I know .

Comment: There are many naming conventions. In the case I alluded to, `James David Van Der Beek Jr.` is a real person. James' last name is `Van Der Beek` http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004735/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm It's not really the answer that's bad but the use case itself. There is no good method to do what the OP wants, not really.